# What does this sentence mean? "You have been working hard, ..."

Tags: american-english

I am not sure the following sentence after yet.

> You have been working hard and providing measurably positive results for your company, yet your pay isn't what it should be or you keep getting skipped over for a promotion or new opportunities to grow.

Would you please let me know more English?

Comment: @snailboat Hi i'm not sure why are you editing my question title, would you let me know? Is there any something wrong point?  From "what is this having a meaning" to "what does this sentence mean?"

Comment: "what is this having a meaning" is ungrammatical.  I guessed that what you meant to say is "What does this sentence mean?"  If I was mistaken, please feel free to roll back my change and edit your question.

Comment: Oh I got it. Your suggestion is correct.

Comment: If I have to use "what is this  having a meaning", what should I edit to do in this sentence?

Comment: ... yet your pay isn't what it should be *because* you keep getting skipped over for promotions *and* new opportunities to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you read it by breaking the sentence into parts and extracting the complex meaning from it:
You have been working hard and providing measurably positive results for your company,

yet

your pay isn't what it should be

or

you keep getting skipped over for a [promotion or new opportunities] to grow.

Means: you are working hard and fetching results as well

but, your pay is much less than what you should get

because you are not considered for a promotion or new opportunity to grow.

Answer (score 1):

After "yet" your sentence says: *Still*, your pay isn't what it should be. (Give a pause here) and then try to understand the second part which says:  You keep getting skipped over for a promotion or new opportunities to grow (i.e. '*you are not being promoted*' to put it in the easiest words)